# Firefox with Vimperator: how to remap the shortcut to the vimperator search bar?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, vimperator

I'm trying to remap the default Vimperator find on page key "/" to "\f" but without luck.

I've tried this command:

```
:nmap \f /
```

but it doesn't work. And a Google search didn't bring any good result. How could I possible do that? I don't think that this Find bar is JS because I can't inspect it as the default FF find bar.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the backslash.

```
nmap \\f /
```

Mind you, it's generally better to use nnoremap:

```
nnoremap \\f /
```

This ensures the binding won't be broken if you ever redefine <kbd>/</kbd>.